# Using alternative preludes in haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-prelude

I'm interested in alternative Preludes.  I understand there are many choices:

1. https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/#cat:Prelude
2. https://guide.aelve.com/haskell/alternative-preludes-zr69k1hc

I understand one simple thing a lot of them fix is text, and another is in functions like `head` that error pretty hard when you might prefer they are safer.

However, when I try to use these alternatives, the behavior in `head`, hmm, just seems to break the function completely, and doesn't look like an improvement to me.  Here are some examples:

### Prelude

```
Prelude> head [1]
1
Prelude> head []
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

### Foundation

```
Foundation> head [1]

<interactive>:6:6: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘NonEmpty c’
                  with actual type ‘[Integer]’
    • In the first argument of ‘head’, namely ‘[1]’
      In the expression: head [1]
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = head [1]
    • Relevant bindings include
        it :: foundation-0.0.21:Foundation.Collection.Element.Element c
          (bound at <interactive>:6:1)
Foundation> head []

<interactive>:7:6: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘NonEmpty c’ with actual type ‘[a0]’
    • In the first argument of ‘head’, namely ‘[]’
      In the expression: head []
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = head []
    • Relevant bindings include
        it :: foundation-0.0.21:Foundation.Collection.Element.Element c
          (bound at <interactive>:7:1)
```

### Safe

```
Safe> head []

<interactive>:22:1: error: Variable not in scope: head :: [a0] -> t
```

### Classy Prelude

```
ClassyPrelude> head [1]

<interactive>:24:6: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘NonNull mono’
                  with actual type ‘[Integer]’
    • In the first argument of ‘head’, namely ‘[1]’
      In the expression: head [1]
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = head [1]
    • Relevant bindings include
        it :: Element mono (bound at <interactive>:24:1)
```

### Relude

```
Relude> head [1]

<interactive>:27:6: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘NonEmpty a’
                  with actual type ‘[Integer]’
    • In the first argument of ‘head’, namely ‘[1]’
      In the expression: head [1]
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = head [1]
    • Relevant bindings include it :: a (bound at <interactive>:27:1)
```

### Rio

```
RIO> head [1]

<interactive>:7:1: error:
    Variable not in scope: head :: [Integer] -> t
```

### Protolude

```
Protolude> head [1]
Just 1
Protolude> head []
Nothing
```

This looks good---it also works for tail, right?

```
Protolude> tail [1]

<interactive>:12:1: error:
    • Variable not in scope: tail :: [Integer] -> t
    • Perhaps you meant ‘tails’ (imported from Protolude)

Protolude> tails [1]
[[1],[]]

Protolude> tails []
[[]]
```

Well, that's not exactly a drop-in replacement.

What am I missing in why this is better, why these functions have been defined if they're just going to fail?

Comment: You're missing the point of alternative preludes. They often provide stronger guarantees against runtime errors _by choosing different type signatures_. If you are changing the types of functions, something is going to break - that's the point!

Comment: Hmm, but what about what seem to be common instructional patterns like `x:xs <- myList` for algorithm design?  Throw these away completely, or these are always happening in the context of having already guaranteed a non-empty list?

Comment: You might also want to look at liquid haskell, which has enough power to check safety like this without requiring different types.

Comment: Whoa!  Liquid Haskell looks neat!

Comment: Rio, no export head, is explicitly approach. hiding head and provide headMaybe and fromMaybe. It is easy to check original head using(it might be not work) when rewrite.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In most cases, they are being introduced because they fail at compile time instead of runtime.

The problem with `Prelude.head` is not (only) that it can fail. It is that it *has* to, since there is no way to take a list `[a]` and always produce an element `a`, since the input list might be empty. There is no easy fix that is a drop-in replacement, a radical change is needed.

A safer, and arguably better prelude can address this issue in one of the following ways:

- remove `head`, so that the programmer won't use a dangerous tool. Any use of `head` will fail, at compile time. Not great, but OK.
- restrict the input type, e.g. `head :: NonEmptyList a -> a`. This will be usable, but the programmer has to adapt the code so to guarantee that the input list is really non empty. Just passing a nonempty list won't do for the compiler -- the compiler wants a *proof*, and rightly so. The *good* news is that the previous code will be littered with compile errors, which will help the programmer spot the parts of the program which need to be fixed.
- restrict the output type, e.g. `head :: [a] -> Maybe a`. This can be used just fine, but the programmer will need to cope with the different result type, and handle all the potential `Nothing`s. Again, the compile time errors will help the programmer to identify where some fixes are needed.

In any case, the programmer has to modify the code. There's no way around it. However, once the compile time errors are resolved, the program is guaranteed to never produce `head: empty list` errors at runtime.

Comment: The Protolude approach looked like what I I guess naively expected as a "working" and "safe" version of head.  This seems to be the third bullet point you mention.  Why would `tail` get different treatment though?

Comment: @Mittenchops That's unclear to me. It seems that Protolude wanted to generalize `head` to Foldables. AFAICS, `tail` can not be generalized in the same way. I would have included it anyway for basic lists, but the authors appear to have made a different choice.

Comment: Thanks, I think this was a clear and helpful answer. I’m disappointed this question will probably be closed as “primarily opinion based,” but you cleared up exactly my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the `relude` authors and I can provide a bit motivation regarding why `relude` choose this behaviour for `head`, `tail`, `last` and `init` functions.

Standard `Prelude` defines `head` in the following way:

```
head :: [a] -> a
```

Alternative preludes often define `head` as follows:

```
head :: [a] -> Maybe a
```

However, `relude` implements it with the following type signature instead:

```
head :: NonEmpty a -> a
```

This design decision makes the library less beginner-friendly (people might not expect such type of the head function) but on the other hand it makes the interface more type-safe.

Another reason for this: if you have function of type `head :: [a] -> Maybe a`, you can't express `head :: NonEmpty a -> a` using your Maybeised version of `head`. But if you have `head` that works with `NonEmpty` it's quite easy to implement `head` that returns `Maybe a`. And `relude` even has the `viaNonEmpty` function for that:

```
viaNonEmpty :: (NonEmpty a -> b) -> ([a] -> Maybe b)
```

See the docs with examples here:

- [`viaNonEmpty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/relude-0.5.0/docs/Relude-List-NonEmpty.html#v:viaNonEmpty)